# I can't get all my form information to automatically capitalize. Help! (It only capitalizes the name)

Tags: javascript, function, capitalize

I can't figure out how to get this script to work. The form works, but it will not translate all of the input data into uppercase? I am not an expert so my code is probably all kinds of wonky. I am sure that it is any easy fix. Thanks.

```
 <HTML>
     <HEAD> <TITLE>Information Form</TITLE></HEAD>
            <SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "JavaScript">

    function alpha(textField) {
            if( textField.calue.lenth !=0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < textField.value.lenth;i++) {
                 var ch= textField.value.charAt(i);

              if((ch < "A" || ch > "Z") && (ch< "a" || ch >"Z")) {
                     return false;
                     }
                }
            }
         else {
         return true; 
           }
          }
    </script>


</head>
<body> 
         <big> 
         Type your name here:
         <input type="text" name="nameInput" onChange="nameInput.value=                                       nameInput.value.toUpperCase()">
         <p>

         Type your street address here:
         <input type="text" address="addressInput" onChange="                                                  addressInput.value=addressInput.value.toUpperCase()">
         <p>

         Type your city and state here:
         <input type="text" cityandstate="stateInput"  onChange="stateInput.value= stateInput.value.toUpperCase()">
            </body>

 <body bgcolor="lightblue">
  <font face=verdana>
  <strong>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why no CSS? `input[type="text"] { text-transform: uppercase }` (after fixing the invalid markup)

Comment: Where do I put the CSS in my code? I apologize, I literally just started coding and a lot of this is still very confusing to me?

Comment: Please also have a look at the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/) and their [Introduction to HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you need a basic understanding of the topic before asking questions about it. There is too much to explain here, and this question will be useless for future viewers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you have a good bit of malformed html in your markup. There should be only one body tag. And all your tags expect your `input` tag should have a closing tag.

Secondly, if all you want to do is to present the text in all caps then you can do that using CSS. If *the way something appears* is all that is important, then using CSS should be your solution most of the time.

```
<html>
  <head> 
    <title>Information Form</title>
      <style>
          input[type=text] {
            text-transform: capitalize;
          }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
       Type your name here:
       <input type="text" name="nameInput" />

       Type your street address here:
       <input type="text" address="addressInput" />

       Type your city and state here:
       <input type="text" cityandstate="stateInput" />
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you- if I wanted to add a button in which the user clicks it and changes everything to capitalization, how would I add the OnClick command to do this?